# android, command line program is not found when executed

Tags: android, command-line, execute

I have rooted my old GT-9301i phone running Android 4.4.2.
I have compiled a command-line program which I can execute in the in BlueStacks emulator in 64 bit.

I have compiled the same program to 32 bit but when I try to execute it then Android reports "file not found", but I can list it with command ls:

The file is located in /data/local/tmp/1

I can see the file using "Root file manager" with permissions rwxrwxrwx.

The terminal emulator shows a #

Rooting of the phone is confirmed by "Root check"

These are the responses from the terminal:

```
ls    
   reports all file including the executable  

ls ./file   
   ./file  

chmod 755 ./file  
   no message

./file
   tmp-mksh: ./file:  No such file or directory

su -c ./file
   tmp-mksh: ./file:  No such file or directory
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How about `chmod +x ./file`, assuming this is a shell script?

Comment: What is the output of `strings ./file | grep -E '\/(ld|linker)'`?

Comment: The instruction  chmod +x ./file gives "Bad mode'  Better would chmod 755 ./file or chmod 777 ./file but note the permissions are already rwxrwxrwx.

Comment: For instruction
strings ./file | grep -E '\/(ld|linker)'  ==>
strings: not found